# Unable to add Index decorator to EF 6.1 code first class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very simple class which i am trying to add a unique constraint to using EF 6.1.2:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace SomeProject.Models
{
    public class User 
    {
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

  issue =>>  [Index("UniqueEmail", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    }
}
```

however i am getting an error stating:

> the type or namespace name 'indexattribute' could not be found

Cheers

Comment: That's because this attribute is in "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema" namespace.

Comment: thanks Evk, I've tried adding that namespace now and the issue persists, could it be anything else?

Comment: You might be missing reference to EntityFramework dll, this attribute is defined there.

Comment: Thats it, thank you! My models project didn't have reference to Entity, i thought it would exist in the other name space